# Ten chairs arranged in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Ten chairs are arranged in a circle. Find the number of subsets of this set of chairs that contain either exactly two adjacent chairs or no adjacent chairs.

Let $1$ be chair, and $0$ be an empty space.

We must have:

$ 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 $

for example.

My previous attempt was disastrous so I'll try recursion:

Let $x(n)$ be the number of arrangements possible starting with $1$ Let $y(n)$ same but start with $0$. And let

$$T(n) = x(n) + y(n)$$

I am after $T(10)$

$x(n) = x(n-1) + y(n-1)$
$y(n) = x(n-1) + y(n-1)$

but this is the confusing part. $x(n) = x(n-1) + y(n-1)$ only if $n = 1,0$ meaning no two before.

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: you seem to only be counting subsets of a certain size.

Comment: For example a subset of $1$ element is not taken into account.

Comment: You're supposed to find recurrence relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the seats from $1$ to $10$, then each subset can be uniquely determined by a binary string of length $10$. For example $0000000000$ is the empty subset.

First we count the subsets with no consecutive $1$'s. They correspond to the sequences with no consecutive $1$'s, that do not start and end in $1$.

There are $f_{10}=144$ sequences without consecutive $1$'s in total and there are $f_{6}=21$ that start and end in $1$, hence $123$ do not start and end in $1$.

---

Now lets count the subsets with exactly one pair of consecutive ones, we use the following trick, the answer is exactly ten times the number of subsets which start with $11$ and have no other consecutive ones, since rotating this subset gives us nine other **different** subsets.

There are $f_6=21$ sequences with exactly one pair of consecutive $1$'s that start with $11$ (because positions 1 and 2 must be ones and positions 10 and 3 must be zeros). So there are $210$ subsets of the second kind.

Adding we get to $333$

Comment: Why do you subtract $f_6$ in the first step and add $10f_7$ in the second step?  Intuitively I would expect you to subtract $f_6$ in the first step and add $10f_6$ in the second step, since the cases which start and end with $1$ with no consecutive $1$s in-between seem (with rotation) to cover all the other possibilities. Some of the $f_7$ cases will start with $11$ and end with $1$, so three adjacent chairs when bent into a circle

Comment: yes, you are 100% correct. Thank you very much for noticing this, I have updated the answer, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: That now looks correct to me.  There is also a relationship with Fibonacci sequences which you could mention.